# How to add video to audio file on iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

I got success to combine audio and video with the help of this link.
[How to add audio to video file on iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440266/how-to-add-audio-to-video-file-on-iphone-sdk)

It create video file of video length but i want to create it of audio length.
For example my video file is of 10 seconds and audio file of 20 seconds then combined video must be 20 seconds.Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC12