# Merge external audio in video at recoding time in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, video

I am developing an app which need to change the audio of camera recorded video, while the time time of recording, but i am only getting the code to change the audio after recording for merge the audio and video, while i want to merge the audio at the time of recording. If any one know how to achieve this feature please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440266/how-to-add-audio-to-video-file-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: @AanchalChaurasia Thanks you for this answer, but this is an alternative solution, this is for if you all ready have a video file in your library, i need to merge the audio while user recording the video from camera.